# DisplayCutout position

Tags: java, android, android-displaycutout

I'm trying to determine the position of the `DisplayCutout`(notch).

The [Android Developer Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/supporting-display-cutouts-on-edge-to.html), state the following:

> In Android P we added APIs to let you manage how your app uses the display cutout area, as well as to check for the presence of cutouts and get their positions.

---

So I tried getting the position of the cutout, this is the only way I was able to get it:

```java
if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    DisplayCutout displayCutout = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootWindowInsets().getDisplayCutout();
    if (displayCutout != null) {
        List<Rect> bounding = displayCutout.getBoundingRects();
        for (int i=0; i<bounding.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("BoundingRect - ", ""+bounding.get(i));
        }                    
    }
}
```

When running the above on a Google Pixel 3XL, it returns `Rect(442, 0 - 998, 171)`.

From the tests I've done, this correlates to:

`442` - Where the cutout starts (on the x-axis), 442px from the left.
`0` - Where the cutout starts (on the y-axis), 0px from the top.
`998` - Where the cutout ends (on the x-axis), 998px from the left.
`171` - Where the cutout ends (on the y-axis), 171px from the top.

---

**My question:** Since the `DisplayCutout` API doesn't return the positions/coordinates separately, what is the best way to get the positions/coordinates from the `String<Rect>`?

The only way I could think of is using String's `substring`, but this feels "hackish"/incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can do the following:

```java
if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    DisplayCutout displayCutout = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootWindowInsets().getDisplayCutout();
    if (displayCutout != null) {
        List<Rect> bounding = displayCutout.getBoundingRects();
        for (int i=0; i<bounding.size(); i++) {
            int left = bounding.get(i).left;
            int right = bounding.get(i).right;
            int top = bounding.get(i).top;
            int bottom = bounding.get(i).bottom;
            Log.e("BoundingLeft - ", ""+left);
            Log.e("BoundingRight - ", ""+right);
            Log.e("BoundingTop - ", ""+top);
            Log.e("BoundingBottom - ", ""+bottom);
        }                    
    }
}
```

So if I use the same example as my question `Rect(442, 0 - 998, 171)`, then the above will return:

```
E/BoundingLeft -: 442
E/BoundingRight -: 998
E/BoundingTop -: 0
E/BoundingBottom -: 171
```

Now I can determine exactly where the `DisplayCutout` is, after converting `px` to `dp` of course.